# JPA OneToMany : Impossible to get the children of an entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, one-to-many

I have a class Question and a class Response like this :

```
@Entity
public class Question implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  protected Long id;
  protected String texte;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="question")
  private List<Reponse> reponses;


@Entity
public class Reponse implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  protected Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
  private Question question;
```

When I call the Type Question from the database, this is supposed to bring me also a List of Response mapped by "question".

But I get a NULL value and  this stack in the List object :

> Error = Exception occured : com.sun.jdi.InvocationException

Does anybody know what it can be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch responses eagerly:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="question", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Reponse> reponses;
```

Comment: Thank you, but what I don't understand is that the program shoud have brought my responses when i called the question.getResponses()... Why it didn't ?

Comment: Because by default `@OneToMany` uses lazy fetch mode.  If you had called `question.getResponses().size()`, the responses should have been loaded.